# Import error (tensorflow) after installing tensorflow-macos and other packages (numpy,pandas,tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hi I am trying to use tensorflow on my Mac (M1) and have installed tensorflow-macos with other dependencies in a conda environment I created. However,when i tried to import tensorflow it gave me an error:

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/ambroseling/Desktop/TensorFlow/mlprojs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 449, in <module>
_ll.load_library(_plugin_dir)
File "/Users/ambroseling/Desktop/TensorFlow/mlprojs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 155, in load_library
py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(lib)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError:   dlopen(/Users/ambroseling/Desktop/TensorFlow/mlprojs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow-plugins/libmetal_plugin.dylib, 6): Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_MPSGraphCompilationDescriptor
Referenced from: /Users/ambroseling/Desktop/TensorFlow/mlprojs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow-plugins/libmetal_plugin.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 12.0)
Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShadersGraph.framework/Versions/A/MetalPerformanceShadersGraph
```

> > > 

I basically followed this step by step guide,https://github.com/mrdbourke/m1-machine-learning-test

What might be the cause to the import error? I would greatly appreciate any help on this. Thank you.

Comment: How are you installing them? Please tell me the command?

Comment: So before I installed tensorflow, I ran sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework to erase any python frameworks because I was worried there might be unknown versions of python I accidentally downloaded that could hinder the installation.then I created a new Conda environment in a file on my desktop, "conda create --prefix /mlprojs" followed by "conda activate",then I did "conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps", "python -m pip install tensorflow-macos", then "python-p install tensorflow-metal","python -m pip install tensorflow-datasets"

Comment: then "conda install jupiter pandas numpy matplotlib scikit learn", then when I tried to import numpy it gave me an error and I found a fix to it which I did "conda install -c conda-forge openblas", other packages seem to be fine when I import it but  tensorflow still gives me an import error

Comment: @AmbroseLing Given that you are seeing missing symbols like _OBJC_CLASS_$_MPSGraphCompilationDescriptor, it means that you have a mismatch between tensorflow and the metal plugin. See [this](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/)  for details. Let us know if the issue still persists. Thanks!